# Null values for Oracle SQL Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, python-2.7

I have a clob datapoint that I must use `.read()` to add it to a list, however, sometimes this column is null, so I need a check first before using the `.read()` property.

I've isolated the portion that is relevant. If I just print data, the null fields print as none. Is not null seems to be the wrong code, but I'm not sure what to use.

```
for currentrow in data:
    if currentrow[8] is not null:
        Product = currentrow[8].read()
    else:
        Product = currentrow[8]
    data = tuple([currentrow[0], currentrow[1], currentrow[2], currentrow[3], currentrow[4], currentrow[5], currentrow[6], currentrow[7], Product])
print data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html):

> The sole value of types.NoneType. None is frequently used to represent
>   the absence of a value, as when default arguments are not passed to a
>   function.

So you may try this:

```
for currentrow in data:
    if currentrow[8] is not None:   <-- Change this from null to None
        Product = currentrow[8].read()
    else:
        Product = currentrow[8]
    data = tuple([currentrow[0], currentrow[1], currentrow[2], currentrow[3], currentrow[4], currentrow[5], currentrow[6], currentrow[7], Product])
print data
```

Answer (score 3):

Python uses the `None` singleton value as a null; `NULL`s from the database are translated to that object:

```
if currentrow[8] is not None:
```

You could collapse that line into just two:

```
for currentrow in data:
    product = currentrow[8] and currentrow[8].read()
    data = currentrow[:8] + (product,)
```

as Python's `and` operator short-circuits and `None` is false in a boolean context. Unless you set a row factory, `cx_Oracle` cursors produce tuples for each row, which you can slice to select just the first 8 elements, then append the 9th to create a new tuple from the two.